# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when installing virtualenv...

Tags: python, permissions, installation, virtualenv

I don't understand why the following gives an error nor how to fix it... any help would be most appreciated. (Note that this question is similar but different than this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580531/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).)

```
dhcp-18-41:WakeUp6 jbs$ sudo -H virtualenv -p 
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15 env
Password:
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 665, in main
    popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Try adding unsafe permission flag to your command. 

"--unsafe-perm=true"

Maybe this'll work.

Comment: From the log message `Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15` - its trying to run that as the python interpreter... but it kinda looks like a directory name to me, hence the permission error. Not sure why its using that path though...

Comment: The path is just where version 2.7.15 is in the computer...

Comment: I get this response: virtualenv: error: no such option: --unsafe-perm ... @Mukarram Pasha: are you sure unsafe is an option with Virtualenv? 
    This is the whole command I tried: sudo -H virtualenv --unsafe-perm=true -p /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15 env

Comment: Why would you run virtualenv with sudo?  root should install to the global environment, create e.g. a group or a separate user if you need to share your virtualenv.  Linux is picky about transferring root permissions to scripts, so if you really want to do this, then start with `sudo su`.

Comment: I´ve tried without sudo and the effect is the same. It´s MAC OS but I assume the issue with sudo su is the same so I tried with it and got the same exact message when being root... any other suggestions @thebjorn ?